# Transposing columns into row uing Perl

Tags: perl

I have below file and want to transpose it from column to row from a specific column.
And to populate the transposed column in an column, say Amount.

Input file(First line is the column name)

```
Market,Merchant,SE_mismatch,Dupe,SENumber,Local,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec

Austria,Asfinag,No,1,9406589846,EUR,1125,1125,1125,1125,1125,1125,1125,1125,1125,1125,1125,1125
Austria,BÖGTY,Yes,1,9406589844,EUR,844,844,844,844,844,844,844,844,844,844,844,844
Austria,Gault,No,1,9496732942,EUR,3375,3375,3375,3375,3375,3375,3375,3375,3375,3375,3375,3375
```

Output (First line is the column name)

```
Market, Merchant,SE_mismatch,Dupe,SENumber,Local,Amount

Austria, Asfin, No, 1,9406589846,EUR, 1125,1
Austria, Asfin, No, 1,9406589846,EUR, 1125,2 
Austria, Asfin, No, 1,9406589846,EUR, 1125,3 
Austria, Asfin, No, 1,9406589846,EUR, 1125,4
Austria, Asfin, No, 1,9406589846,EUR, 1125,5 
Austria, Asfin, No, 1,9406589846,EUR, 1125,6 
Austria, Asfin, No, 1,9406589846,EUR, 1125,7 
Austria, Asfin, No, 1,9406589846,EUR, 1125,8 
Austria, Asfin, No, 1,9406589846,EUR, 1125,9
Austria, Asfin, No, 1,9406589846,EUR, 1125,10 
Austria, Asfin, No, 1,9406589846,EUR, 1125,11  
Austria, Asfin, No, 1,9406589846,EUR, 1125,12 
Austria, BÖWG, Yes, 1,9406589844,EUR, 844,1 
Austria, BÖWG, Yes, 1,9406589844,EUR, 844,2 
Austria, BÖWG, Yes, 1,9406589844,EUR, 844,3 
Austria, BÖWG, Yes, 1,9406589844,EUR, 844,4 
Austria, BÖWG, Yes, 1,9406589844,EUR, 844,5  
Austria, BÖWG, Yes, 1,9406589844,EUR, 844,6 
Austria, BÖWG, Yes, 1,9406589844,EUR, 844,7  
Austria, BÖWG, Yes, 1,9406589844,EUR, 844,8  
Austria, BÖWG, Yes, 1,9406589844,EUR, 844,9 
Austria, BÖWG, Yes, 1,9406589844,EUR, 844,10  
Austria, BÖWG, Yes, 1,9406589844,EUR, 844,11 
Austria, BÖWG, Yes, 1,9406589844,EUR, 844,12 
Austria, Gault, No, 1,9496732942,EUR, 3375,1
Austria, Gault, No, 1,9496732942,EUR, 3375,2 
Austria, Gault, No, 1,9496732942,EUR, 3375,3
Austria, Gault, No, 1,9496732942,EUR, 3375,4
Austria, Gault, No, 1,9496732942,EUR, 3375,5
Austria, Gault, No, 1,9496732942,EUR, 3375,6
Austria, Gault, No, 1,9496732942,EUR, 3375,7 
Austria, Gault, No, 1,9496732942,EUR, 3375,8 
Austria, Gault, No, 1,9496732942,EUR, 3375,9 
Austria, Gault, No, 1,9496732942,EUR, 3375,10
Austria, Gault, No, 1,9496732942,EUR, 3375,11
Austria, Gault, No, 1,9496732942,EUR, 3375,12
```

**I have updated the above output by adding the new column in the end of every line.** 
I have tried by modifiyng below code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#This is to Transpose the Data from Column to row.

use strict;
use warnings;

my $fn = shift || "testf1";
my $specific_column_number = shift || 1;
my $count = 1;
my $n = 0;

open( my $fh, "<", $fn) or die "Could not open file '$fn' : $!\n";
my @head = split (/,/, scalar <$fh>);
print join(",", @head[0..($specific_column_number - 1)]) . "\n";
while (<$fh>) {
    my @fields = split /,/;
    next if @fields == 0;
    my $start_of_row = 
       join(",",(@fields[0..($specific_column_number -1)]));
    my @rest_of_fields = @fields[$specific_column_number..$#fields];
    for (@rest_of_fields) {
        print "$start_of_row,$_,$count\n";
        $n++;
        $count++;
    }
}
close ($fh);
```

But its couinting the line in an incremental order like below.

```
Market, Merchant,SE_mismatch,Dupe,SENumber,Local
Austria, Asfin, No, 1,9406589846,EUR, 1125,1
Austria, Asfin, No, 1,9406589846,EUR, 1125,2 
Austria, Asfin, No, 1,9406589846,EUR, 1125,3 
Austria, Asfin, No, 1,9406589846,EUR, 1125,4
Austria, Asfin, No, 1,9406589846,EUR, 1125,5 
Austria, Asfin, No, 1,9406589846,EUR, 1125,6 
Austria, Asfin, No, 1,9406589846,EUR, 1125,7 
Austria, Asfin, No, 1,9406589846,EUR, 1125,8 
Austria, Asfin, No, 1,9406589846,EUR, 1125,9
Austria, Asfin, No, 1,9406589846,EUR, 1125,10 
Austria, Asfin, No, 1,9406589846,EUR, 1125,11  
Austria, Asfin, No, 1,9406589846,EUR, 1125,12 
Austria, BÖWG, Yes, 1,9406589844,EUR, 844,13
Austria, BÖWG, Yes, 1,9406589844,EUR, 844,14
Austria, BÖWG, Yes, 1,9406589844,EUR, 844,15
Austria, BÖWG, Yes, 1,9406589844,EUR, 844,16
Austria, BÖWG, Yes, 1,9406589844,EUR, 844,17
........ and so on
```

Please guide me or give any suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. You have to read documentation, and try something by yourself

Comment: What did you try to achieve this?

Comment: You must reset the `$count` counter for each row.. Put `my $count = 1;` inside the `while` loop.

Comment: @Håkon Hægland **Thanks!!** once again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a template for a solution:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $fn = 'File1';
my $specific_column_number = 6;
my $new_column_name = 'Amount';

open( my $fh, "<", $fn) or die "Could not open file '$fn' : $!\n";
my @head = split (/,/, scalar <$fh>);
print join(",", @head[0..($specific_column_number - 1)]) . "\n";
while (<$fh>) {
    my @fields = split /,/;
    next if @fields == 0;
    my $start_of_row = 
       join(",", (@fields[0..($specific_column_number -1)], $new_column_name));
    my @rest_of_fields = @fields[$specific_column_number..$#fields];
    for (@rest_of_fields) {
        print "$start_of_row, $_\n";
    }
}
close ($fh);
```